# Recursively zipping a directory in golang

Tags: go, zip

I essentially want to implement these commands in Golang:

```
cd somedir ; zip -r ../zipped.zip . * ; cd ..
```

I'm trying to zip folders and files within a parent directory without including the parent directory. This post is similar:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/521011/zip-an-archive-without-including-parent-directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"how do I recursively zip in Golang"

Something like this...

```
package rzip

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func RecursiveZip(pathToZip, destinationPath string) error {
    destinationFile, err := os.Create(destinationPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    myZip := zip.NewWriter(destinationFile)
    err = filepath.Walk(pathToZip, func(filePath string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        relPath := strings.TrimPrefix(filePath, filepath.Dir(pathToZip))
        zipFile, err := myZip.Create(relPath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fsFile, err := os.Open(filePath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = io.Copy(zipFile, fsFile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = myZip.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

As for problems with docx files and your implementation, it's difficult to see what the problem might be without being able to see your code.

EDIT:

To create a zip with all files in the same dir you just need to change the path of the files you create inside your archive.

```
    relPath := strings.TrimPrefix(filePath, filepath.Dir(pathToZip))
    zipFile, err := myZip.Create(relPath)
```

Becomes

```
     flatPath := filepath.Base(pathToZip)
     zipFile, err := myZip.Create(flatPath)
```

To maintain directory structure, but omit the root directory

```
     relPath := strings.TrimPrefix(filePath, pathToZip)
     zipFile, err := myZip.Create(relPath)
```

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: When I run cd somedir ; zip -r ../zipped.zip . * ; cd .. , that will zip without including the parent directory. How do I use RecursiveZip to do that?

Comment: You just need to change the path of the files you create inside your archive. See edit in the answer.

Comment: I appreciate it! I'll give it a shot. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Really appreciate you!

Comment: I was getting an empty archive.  I had to change the relPath to: use forward slashes instead of back slashes, and also remove the preceeding forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [abstract storage API](https://github.com/viant/afs)

In this case, you can simply use the following snippet:

```
service := afs.New()
ctx := context.Background()
err := service.Copy(ctx, "file:///tmp/somedir", "file:/tmp/zipped.zip/zip:///", )
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: How does this naming format `"file:/tmp/zipped.zip/zip:///"` work? something like `zip:///tmp/zipped.zip` makes more sense

Comment: @PhaniRithvij   afs use the following nameing   [optional extension/]PROTOCOL://host/path

Comment: as reference: 
https://github.com/viant/afs/blob/342c389a775898fb374bb95632ec1caddc7c75ea/url/scheme.go#L28

Comment: This allows you very flexible addressing for example:  s3:/mybucket/folder/file.zip//:zip///folderinArchive/somefile.txr

Comment: while the actual protocol always uses '://',    extension protocol uses ':/'

Comment: Great will take a look at the library.

Answer (score 0):

### Cross Platform Solution

I couldn't get @Mark Mellar's answer to work correctly for windows (file names were directory paths rather than the zip containing the directories). The following adaptation is cross-platform compatible.

```
// ZipDirectory returns an io.Reader containing the provided directory
// after passing it through a zip writer.
func ZipDirectory(dir string) (io.Reader, error) {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    w := zip.NewWriter(&buf)
    err := filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // Strip the absolute path up to the current directory, then trim off a leading
        // path separator (for Windows) and replace all instances of Windows path separators
        // with forward slashes as required by the w.Create method.
        f, err := w.Create(strings.Replace(strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimPrefix(path, dir), string(filepath.Separator)), "\\", "/", -1))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        in, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = io.Copy(f, in)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &buf, nil
}
```

Comment: it does not work using filepath.Rel ? https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Rel

Comment: you could declare the strings.NewReplacer instance in the package scope to avoid multiple JIT initialization.

Comment: @mh-cbon I'm not sure if filepath.Rel would work given that `dir` doesn't have to be an absolute path itself.

Comment: how about this https://play.golang.org/p/YC-JjWfFvLI ?

Comment: @mh-cbon That's additional lines of code, does it provide any additional benefits? If so, I'm happy to update my answer.